# Children's book where a girl and her friend turned into cats

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel

I’m looking for a story I read as a child..it was about a girl called “Beans” was short for something..she had a friend with ginger hair and they ended up turning into cats. I’m sure the friend also got possessed by the cat…I’ve searched everywhere for this but I can’t remember the name of the author. Read it in the 90s.